# Dealing with scanner exceptions for every input in a class

Tags: java, exception

I want to take an integer but avoid an exception from a string input. I am having a lot of trouble with this, but it seems like it should be so basic. People have mentioned a try/catch, I did this and it worked, but once I put it in a loop I couldn't break the loop, plus I have a lot of input requests and it seems like a lot of code just for a line of input. Someone told me you can use Integer.parsInt but I can't get that to work either, so I think that's incorrect.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

   Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("enter something");
   int num = Integer.parseInt(keyboard.nextLine());
   System.out.println(num);

}
```

I tested it out and it didn't work. It still threw an exception. So what are ways I can take achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Why couldn't you break out of the loop when you put it into a try catch block?

Comment: I have added an answer, let me know if it helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check something like that

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Please enter an int: ");
String s = sc.next();
while(!s.matches("\\d+")) {
    System.out.println("Input is not valid! Re enter an integer!");
    System.out.print("Please enter an int: ");
    s = sc.next();
}
int numWeight = Integer.parseInt(s);
System.out.println("Int: " + numWeight);
```

Like this you execute the Integer.parseInt after you are sure that the string input is an integer.

Comment: Thanks, this works perfect. I got it working in my programme but didn't end up using it. It was a group assignment at uni and the specs had the assumption of only an integer input. but it's useful to know for future projects.